# Double exclamation marks in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I have this code:

```
ghci>let listOfFuns = map (*) [0..]
ghci>(listOfFuns !! 4) 5
20
```

1. what does this `!!` mean?

I saw example about double exclamation like this:

```
ghci> [1,2,3,4]!!1 
ghci> 2
```

But it seems don't apply to my question example.

2. how to understand this function. need explanations.

Comment: [Hoogle](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=%21%21) is extremely useful.

Comment: just been reading the same [tutorial](http://learnyouahaskell.com/higher-order-functions)!

Answer (score 62, accepted):

[`!!`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v%3a-33--33-) indexes lists. It takes a list and an index, and returns the item at that index. If the index is out of bounds, it returns ⊥.

Comment: In ghci, type `:t (!!)` to obtain its type which is likely along the lines of `[a] -> Int -> a`. From this, it's easy to deduce that it extracts one of the elements of the list based on the second parameter.

Answer (score 2):

Might find it easier to think in equivilances

```hs
let listOfFuns = map (*) [0..] in (listOfFuns !! 4) 5
== (map (*) [0..] !! 4) 5
== (map (*) [0, 1, 2, ...] !! 4) 5
== ([(0*), (1*), (2*), ...] !! 4) 5
== (4*) 5
== 20
```

You can see here `map (*) [0..]` is a [Int → Int], so when you take the 3rd element of it (which is what `!! 4` does) you get a function Int → Int. Finally 5 is applied to that function to give you 20.